# How do you make a .command file autostart on system bootup?

Tags: macos, applescript, script, automation

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.4.

How do you make a `.command` file autostart on system bootup?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It looks like you want to run a Terminal file on system startup, is that right? Could provide more information on what you want to achieve when running that file?

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-in-mac-os-x